# Нажатие на кнопку и смена состояния в runtime

Tags: unity3d

Вопрос по UI. Имеется кнопка с повешеными на нее спрайтами соответсвующими состояниям - нажата и активна. При запуске игры все работает как нужно - нажал на кнопку - отображение поменялось.
Как программно вызвать нажатие этой кнопки чтобы также поменялось ее состояние?
К примеру, кнопка в игре забиндена на кнопку на клавиатуре, если нажать на кнопку на клавиатуре чтобы также кнопка в игре поменялась?

Comment: Вы можете конечно написать `button.onClick.Invoke()`, это вызовет все обработчики которые на ней висят, но мне кажется тут или что-то не так с архитектурой или я чего-то не понимаю. Возможно проще будет просто вызвать программно ту же функцию которая в обработчике?

Comment: Да, можно вызвать ту же функцию, но кнопка не изменит своего состояния. Попробую Invoke()

Comment: То есть надо чтобы у кнопки проигрывалась анимация?

Comment: Да, именно так-чтобы проиграла анимация

Answer (score 0):

Мне известно три способа сделать это, хотя в каждом есть свои недостатки.

---

#### Поставить Transition = Animation

Очевидный недостаток этого способа - необходимость создавать аниматор и настраивать его. Но тогда вы сможете управлять анимацией при помощи тех же самых триггеров, что и код кнопки.

---

#### Сделать класс - наследник Button

Тогда можно будет вызывать protected методы, а за состояния как раз они и отвечают. Но это требует изучения документации или исходников, чтобы не сломать логику состояний.

---

#### Написать полностью свою кнопку

Начинаем так, можно еще `IPointerClickHandler` добавить:

```
public class MyButton :
MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler {
```

Потом нужно добавить реализацию всех методов, на которые будет ругаться компилятор. Вы можете делать здесь что угодно и оставлять публичными хоть все методы, и логика будет вам понятна, так как вы сами создали ее, но сами понимаете, вам в этом случае придется изобрести велосипед.